# LINQ Sum() function fails without using ToList()

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Following throws runtime error shown below. Although it compiles fine:

```
float? totalSum = (from t in _context.Orders
               join c in _context.Customers.Where(c => c.region=="NW")
               on t.CustomerId equals c.CustomerId 
      select t.price).Sum();
```

**Error**:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Single]'.
```

But the following works (only difference is that I'm using `ToList()` before applying `.Sum()` - but according to the [definition of Sum()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.110).aspx) it should work without using `ToList()` - correct?

```
float? totalSum = (from t in _context.Orders
               join c in _context.Customers.Where(c => c.region=="NW")
               on t.CustomerId equals c.CustomerId 
      select t.price).ToList().Sum();
```

**UPDATE**:

The datatype of `price` attribute is `float?` that maps to datatype `real` in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: What are the actual types of all the variables and properties? How are your entities mapped? The error suggests that either `price` is not a `float?` or your mappings are messed up.

Comment: @JeffMercado After reading your comment I double checked to verify that `price` is indeed `float?`

Comment: try using `select t.price ?? 0.0f` instead. Apparently something is screwing up the translation so sidestepping the problem fields all together might fix it. But still... it would help to see the _actual_ class definitions and the _actual_ mappings... there's not  enough information here to diagnose the problem and you still haven't provided that info.

Comment: @nam All your recent posts with `float` issues are apparently bugs in EF Core. Anytime you have a valid LINQ query and get exception like this, go directly search their issue tracker :)

Comment: It was bug in EF and fixed here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7136

Comment: Also filed general purpose issue https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/8906 to fix such things for all functions we translate.

Comment: Also for clarification of all comment questions, `ToList` call works because it will fetch all data in memory (which are still float type) and then compute sum so type is preserved. When you do Sum on server, that changes the type to double

Answer (score 0):

> select t.price

could yield null which the error message you receive reflects. Either check for null:

> select t.price ?? 0.0f

or go for the .ToList();
You may also implement your own Sum() that checks for null.

Comment: ToList()? instantiates a new objects with default values set to 0 vs. IEnumerable which can be filled with anything that has implemented IEnumerable includeing []s.